# Node.JS - http.request, double escaping JSON

Tags: json, http, node.js

I am trying to make a POST http.request in Node to an API where the body is JSON. I convert my object to a JSON string using JSON.stringify, however when I write the string to the request and look at my request it double escapes the data i.e. \ becomes \\\\.

```
        jsonData = JSON.stringify(myObject)
        // everything is a correct JSON string, with slashes escapped once
        post_req.write(jsonData, 'binary')
        post_req.end()
        console.log post_req // the JSON string was actually sent double escapped
```

Any tips on how to stop Node automatically double escaping the JSON?
When I take my jsonData and curl or [hurl.it](http://hurl.it/) it to the server everything works as expected.

Comment: Are you using any HTTP frameworks or libraries (e.g. express.js) or just plain-old node.js without any dependencies?  Some context around your code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: I am using express however the post_req is just an instance of nodes http.request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data isn't binary, it's a string, so just omit the 'binary' parameter to `post_req.write(jsonData)`, and it will use utf8, which is what you want. Are you sure the double-escaping is really going over the wire and you aren't being tricked by trying to `console.log` the post_req object itself?

Comment: I had also tried utf-8, the reason I was using binary is because thats what I use for the curl command. I am being tricked by console.log, silly mistake, problem must be else where.